# Defining a return for a very simple manual Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that does this:

```
public static int Run(int myvalue, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {myvalue}");

    if (myvalue == 1) return 1;

    return (myvalue + 1);
}
```

I created it directly in the portal; however, my attempt at the bindings are probably wrong:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "myvalue"
    },
    {
      "type": "int",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

When I run it inside the portal, it gives me a 202 (accepted), but doesn't output the return value from the function.

My question is, basically, why am I not getting any output; however, I suppose my first question should be (is), *should* I be getting output; and if so, what's wrong with my binding?

This is a simplified version of a slightly more complex function, that I intend to use as a condition inside a logic app (hence why I need a return value).

Comment: How do you expect the output to be returned? If you want it in the HTTP response, you need an HttpTrigger binding. There's a sample for it, just hit New Function. If you just want to log it, `log.Info(something);`.

Comment: For the minute, I'll accept just seeing it in the output of the test harness within the portal (as you can see - there is logging in the function already)

Comment: Then replace your return statement with `log.Info(...);`. You are returning to noone. A proper output binding (Http or Queue) would make more sense.

Comment: I don’t see logging in the output, because logging isn’t a return value of the function

Comment: If you want to use it in a Logic App you need to return that value in the HTTP response: `type: httpTrigger` - example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#trigger---c-script-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is not a supported type for manual trigger. You should be seeing an error like this in the logs:

> [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.ManualTriggerCSharp1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Can't bind ManualTriggerAttribute to type 'System.Int32'.

If you change the parameter type to `string`, logging should work:

```cs
public static void Run(string myvalue, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# manually triggered function called with input: {myvalue}");
}
```

Now, there is no point in returning anything from manual trigger. You can keep returning an `int` but it will be ignored. But remove the second binding:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "manualTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "myvalue"
    }
   ],
   "disabled": false
 }
```

To return a value, you probably need to switch to HTTP trigger, read the data from HTTP request and return HTTP response.

Comment: Strange, it’s not giving an error.  Are there any supported numeric return types?  What I’m returning is a number, after all.